# how to block ipv4 list with iptables/ipset, but exclude certain ports

Tags: iptables, ipset

I have the following rules in a bash (in that order):

```
# blocklist.txt contains:
#192.168.1.39

for ip in $(cat blocklist.txt); do
    iptables -I INPUT -s $ip -p tcp -m multiport --dports 137:139,445 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -I FORWARD -d $ip -p tcp -m multiport --dports 137:139,445 -j ACCEPT
done

ipset flush banip
ipset -N -! banip hash:ip maxelem 1000000
for ip in $(cat blocklist.txt); do
    ipset -A banip "$ip"
done
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
```

where "blocklist" includes ipv4 addresses. but my rules block the list and do not allow access to those ports excluded in the ALLOW rules.

*Note 1: I have tried with `hash:ip` and `hash:net` and the same result*

*Note 2: if i add ACCEPT rules for -p udp the ports are still blocked.*

According to [HERE](https://serverfault.com/a/986352/480349) you should do this, but this does not open the desired ports for this list either:

```
ipset flush banip
ipset -N -! banip hash:ip maxelem 1000000
for ip in $(cat blocklist.txt); do
    ipset -A banip "$ip"
done
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 137:139,445 -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -m multiport --dports 137:139,445 -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
```

and According to [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/548666/how-do-i-allow-only-certain-ipset-sets-to-access-a-certain-port-with-iptables) you should do this, but the same happen:

```
ipset flush banip
ipset -N -! banip hash:ip maxelem 1000000
for ip in $(cat blocklist.txt); do
    ipset -A banip "$ip"
done
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set banip src,dts -p tcp -m multiport --dport 137:139,445 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set banip src,dts -p tcp -m multiport --dport 137:139,445 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
```

my data:

- iptables v1.8.7
- ipset v7.15
- ubuntu 22.04

ipset -L banip

```
Name: banip
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 5
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 1000000 bucketsize 12 initval 0xebeb2f5c
Size in memory: 240
References: 16
Number of entries: 1
Members:
192.168.1.39
```

iptables -L -v -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4185 packets, 7480K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst multiport dports 137:139,445
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src multiport dports 137:139,445
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 170 packets, 29238 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst multiport dports 137:139,445
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src multiport dports 137:139,445
```

What's wrong with my rules?. Thanks

**Update:**

I also created a new list with the ports and allowed it before the block list, no results.

```
# allowports.txt contains:
# 137
# 138
# 139
# 445

ipset flush allowports
ipset -N -! allowports bitmap:port range 0-65535
for ports in $(cat allowports.txt); do
    ipset -A allowports "$ports"
done
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set allowports src,dts -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set allowports src,dts -j ACCEPT

ipset flush banip
ipset -N -! banip hash:ip maxelem 1000000
for ip in $(cat blocklist.txt); do
    ipset -A banip "$ip"
done
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
```

ipset -L allowports

```
Name: allowports
Type: bitmap:port
Revision: 3
Header: range 0-65535
Size in memory: 8264
References: 16
Number of entries: 4
Members:
137
138
139
445
```

new iptables -L -v -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 757 packets, 619K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
   42  3883 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set allowports dst
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set allowports src
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 197 packets, 11983 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip dst
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set banip src
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set allowports dst
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set allowports src
```

**Solved!**

As suggested by @MarkWagner I have reversed the rules and the problem is solved. This is because iptables rules are executed in order. However, the --insert (-I) rules are placed in the header, above the --append (-A) rules, but if there are two "--insert" rules, the last one will be the one in the header. header (first). So the right way is:

```
ipset flush banip
ipset -N -! banip hash:ip maxelem 1000000
for ip in $(cat blocklist.txt); do
    ipset -A banip "$ip"
done
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set banip src,dts -j DROP
for protocol in $(echo udp tcp); do
   iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set banip src,dts -$protocol -m multiport --dports 137,138,139,445 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set banip src,dts -$protocol -m multiport --dports 137,138,139,445 -j ACCEPT
done
```

Comment: Input - dport, output -sport, forward - inbound - dport, outbound - sport

Comment: @gapsf fix it. thk

Comment: Showing `iptables -L -v -n` would make answering this question easier.

Comment: @MarkWagner add out of iptables

Comment: Whatever you doing, you're getting the ordering of the rules backwards. The first matching rule is applied and you have the DROPs before the ACCEPTs. (You also have duplicate rules.)

Comment: @MarkWagner solved! thanks